# How to write math expressions in LaTeX within Octave

Tags: matlab, latex, octave, matlab-figure

I'm using Octave to draw some graphs. But when I write this in Octave:

```
x=linspace(0,3);y=x.^2.*sin(x);
plot(x,y); 
line([2,2],[0,2^2*sin(2)]);
str = '$$ \int_{0}^{2} x^2\sin(x) dx $$';
text (0.25,2.5,str,'Interpreter','latex');
annotation('arrow','X',[0.32,0.5],'Y',[0.6,0.4]);
```

In octave I got this:

[image: graph with LaTeX code]

and in MATLAB I got this:

[image: graph with properly formatted equation]

I want to know if there are any solutions to change the output to a MATLAB style.

Comment: Octave relies on a locally installed latex distribution. If there is none, or not in path as required by octave ([see the docs](https://docs.octave.org/latest/_0022latex_0022-interpreter.html)), it treats the latex string as plain text (formatter `"none"`). You may also try the `"tex"` formatter instead of `"latex"`, which has built in support

Comment: I can confirm that on my system running octave 8.2.0 on linux mint with texlive installed, I get the properly formatted latex string.

Comment: @kikon 's comment should be the accepted answer. change "latex" to "tex" solve the problem. Of course, you must have Tex distribution installed at first, e.g. Tex Live.